# Plus-que-parfait et imparfait : concordance ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, concordance-des-temps

J'ai trouvé [cet exercice](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/souvenirs-et--plus-que-parfait-!-.html) qu'il fallait compléter avec les verbes entre parenthèses :

> Elle m' (*dire*) **avait dit** que les enfants au petit déjeuner
>   (*manger*) **mangeaient** la meilleure confiture du monde : une
>   confiture que ma grand-mère (*préparer*) **préparait** avec les oranges
>   amères, les citrons, les prunes, les pommes et les figues des arbres
>   qui (*pousser*) **avaient poussé** dans son jardin.

J'ai deux questions par rapport à l'exercice :

1. Pourquoi je dois mettre « préparait » si la préparation est un évènement qui arrive avant « manger » ? Moi, j'aurais mis « avait préparé »...
2. Si en tout cas la bonne réponse est *préparait*, pourquoi je dois mettre « avaient poussé » ?

Je comprends que le plus-que-parfait est un temps utilisé pour décrire une action qui a eu lieu avant une autre action dans le passé, mais cette utilisation est un peu compliquée dans ce cas-ci.

Comment: En espagnole les mêmes temps de verbe seraient utilisés ici. Ella me habia dicho que para el desayuno los niños comian.....etc. Une action continue avant un moment dans le passé. Elle m'a dit ou elle m'avait dit seraient suivi de l'imparfait pour des actions continues.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce texte, deux temps du passé sont utilisés, le plus-que-parfait et l'imparfait. Le premier décrit une action antérieure à un fait passé (j'ai fait des pâtes avant-hier, je les ai mangées hier, on dira "j'ai mangé les pâtes que j'avais préparées la veille") et le deuxième une action continue s'étant déroulée dans le passé ("quand j'étais petit, je mangeait des pâtes").
"Elle m'avait dit" est l'action principale, qui fixe l'histoire dans le temps. Ensuite, on parle d'une chose dans le passé, plus lointain que le moment auquel "elle te dit". Il s'agit d'une habitude, les enfants mangeait la meilleure confiture du monde, que sa grand-mère préparait. Cela se renouvelait, ce qui justifie l'utilisation de l'imparfait. Au plus-que-parfait, la phrase aurait été "ils avaient mangé la confiture que ma grand-mère avait préparée" soit un évènement précis ne s'étant déroulé qu'une fois. Ensuite, "avait poussé" signifie que les arbres n'ont poussé qu'une seule fois. Les deux temps peuvent être utilisés, soient ils poussent en permanence, soit, dans le cas du texte, cet événement ne s'est pas reproduit.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!